# How to compute the number of times number i appears just after number j?

Tags: matlab

For instance, in `[ 1 2 2 3 2 3 1 ]`, the number of times `3` appears after `2` is 2.
How can I use MATLAB to do this calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A = [ 1 2 2 3 2 3 1 ]
n = 2
m = 3
```

find where all the numbers `n` or `m` occur:

```
idxN = A == n;
idxM = A == m;
```

count where the two index vectors above (i.e. `idxN` and `idxM`) overlap after shifting `idxM` one element to the left:

```
sum(idxN(1:end-1) & idxM(2:end))
```

Note you can do this in one line too:

```
sum(A(1:end-1)==n & A(2:end)==m)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Dan's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33687918/2586922) is probably the cleanest.

Here's another way, exploiting the (undocumented?) fact that [`strfind`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) works for numbers too:

```
data = [1 2.1 2.1 3.4 0 2.1 3.4 1];
pattern = [2.1 3.4];
result = numel(strfind(data, pattern));
```

The nice thing is that this can be generalized to more than two numbers, for example defining `pattern = [2.1 3.4 1]`.